# How to bind another function after using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQquery validation plugin and I want to execute another function after validation based on the validation result.

```
$('#profileForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function() {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    success: function(label, element) {}

})
```

How to bind another function that will execute every time after validation?

Comment: `function (){}.bind(context)`

Comment: you want to extend the validation rules? or you want to run your custom function after validation Success/Failure?

Comment: I want run my custom function after validation failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't

```
$('#profileForm').validate({
  submitHandler: function() {
    /** handle submit stuff **/
    callSomeFx();
  },
  …
});
```

just do that?

You could define another function like so:

```
function onSubmit(){}
```

and set this as »submitHandler« to the `.validate()` configuration.